# Fedora list all packages not in a "clean" install

Tags: fedora, package-management

Is there some tool to show me all packages I've installed that are not part of the set of packages that comes with a "clean" install?

I'm just cleaning out packages I don't use any more prior to upgrading from F15 to F16 (the computer has passed hands a number of times and is slowly accumulating unused packages).

I don't want to actually do a fresh install of F16 (so that I can keep some particular packages that I use & config files etc), but I'd like to restore my F15 to as close to a "clean" install as possible before the upgrade.

I've done a little with `rpmcleaner` and `cleanup-packages`, but I'd prefer just a list of "packages not in a fresh install of F15", bonus points if it displays in an 'Add/Remove Software'-type interface (purely because it easily displays package descriptions and it's easier to uncheck a checkbox than `yum erase whats-the-package-name-again`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***NOT*** responsible if this breaks your system...

```
comm -3 <(rpm -qa | sort) <(rpm -qa 'packager=Fedora Project' | sort) | grep -v '^gpg-pubkey-'
```

Comment: (Could whoever it was explain the -1 so that I can make a more informed decision as to the pitfalls/benifits of usin this?) So I guess packages that come with fedora by default have 'packager=Fedora Project'? Why do you do the `grep` bit (I don't have access to that computer today but will play around tomorrow).

Comment: The keys used to verify signed RPMs are installed into the rpmdb with the name of "gpg-pubkey"; we exclude them since we can't automatically tell which are Fedora's, and removing Fedora's keys could cause problems.

Comment: Thanks - it works well enough. Of course I wouldn't blindly delete everything on that list, but it does bring to my attention packages I don't use at all